# Simplicial differential graded algebra and a filtration

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, simplicial-stuff, differential-graded-algebras

Let $A$ be a simplicial differential algebra, i.e. for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ a differential graded algebra $(A_n,d_n)$ and for each weakly increasing map $f \colon [n] \to [m]$ a morphism $f_* \colon A_n \to A_m$ such that $f_*$ and $d$ commute.
Consider the increasing filtration $F_{\bullet} A_n$ defined by $F_k A_n = \sum_{f\colon [k] \to [n]} \operatorname{Im} f_*$ where the sum is taken over all weakly increasing maps.

I claim that $\operatorname{gr}_F^\bullet H^\bullet (A_n,d_n) \cong H^\bullet(\operatorname{gr}_F^\bullet A_n,d_n)$ are isomorphic as algebras. Is it true?

It is equivalent to prove that the differential is strict, i.e. $\operatorname{Im} d \cap F_kA_n = d(F_kA_n)$. For $k=n-1$ it follows from Lemma 8.3.7 of "Weibel - An introduction to homolgical algebra" by noticing that $F_{n-1}A_n = D_n(A)$ is the degenerate subcomplex.
I also wonder if the direct sum decomposition generalize to $A_n= \cap_{f\colon [n]\to [k]} \ker f_* \oplus F_kA_n$.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the algebra structure anywhere. Is this just a question about simplicial cochain complexes? If so, I'd use the Dold-Kan correspondence to write $A=K(NA)$ as the denormalisation of the chain cochain complex $NA$. That gives a natural expression for $A_n$ as a direct sum of various copies of $N_kA$ for $k\le n$.

Comment: I'd like to have $\operatorname{gr}_F^\bullet H^\bullet (A_n,d_n) \cong H^\bullet(\operatorname{gr}_F^\bullet A_n,d_n)$ as algebra, not only as vector space

Comment: But presumably you've already got a map in one direction, so you can disregard algebra structure when proving quasi-isomorphism. Strictness of the differential isn't an algebra statement.